# Memory efficient way to traverse all rows of a table with Entity Framework (7)

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 7 and I have to merge multiple tables with many data into a common table, regularly.

Is there a memory efficient and easy way to traverse each table in batches with Entity Framework?

Currently I'm counting the rows and then calculate the number of skips/pages and traverse by hand.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? If you are copying rows into another table, then the most efficient way would be to do it directly in SQL and not EF (e.g. `INSERT INTO MergedTable SELECT * FROM Table1`)

Comment: @DavidG the merge requires intermediate steps and transformations. I know SQL vey well for over 20 years. My question here very specifically is about entity framework idioms which I rarely use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can be done in SQL, something like that should be done in SQL. If it pretty much requires to be done in-application then I can suggest the following considerations:

1. Use a bounded DbContext set up with just the Entity configurations involved with only enough fields declared from each to satisfy the details you need to merge. (If you don't need everything)
2. Ensure that you are using a "fresh" scoped DbContext. Meaning that if you are using DI and the context in question has loaded/added other tracked entity references, consider scoping a new DbContext instance for this operation rather than using the injected one. To keep DI patterns happy, inject something like a DbContextScopeFactory for use for cases like this where you need an isolated, clean DbContext.
3. Build your query for the two entity sets and use `Skip` and `Take` within a `while` loop to extract a reasonable set of rows from each table, do your processing, and insert.
4. If the source rows do not need to be updated themselves, use `AsNoTracking` when reading those source entities. This will keep DB read operations fast as when the DbContext starts tracking more entities, that is more time it will spend checking existing references when asked for more data and saving new data.
5. After adding the new entity into the merged results and saving, detach it from the DbContext to keep further DbContext operations quick. `context.Entry(newMergedEntity).EntityState = EntityState.Detached;

If you need to update the source entities, or want to insert entities in smaller batches between `SaveChanges` call, then instead of detaching individual entities via `EntityState`, use `context.ChangeTracker.Clear()` to remove all current tracking.